# Добавление нескольких записей в базу Kohana

Tags: orm, php, kohana, mysql

Возможно ли реализовать добавление нескольких записей в таблицу одним запросом с помощью ORM?
В частности необходимо перенести содержимое файла .csv в базу (число строк ~40000).
Если нет возможности то что целесообразнее использовать: цикл ORM, либо методы Database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Методы `Database` конечно. А вообще в `Kohana` говорят крутая `ORM` ищите в сети, по любому что-то есть.

Answer (score 3):

Ну есть такая конструкция

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/user/first.csv' INTO TABLE `firsttable`
```

так же есть и параметры у неё, о них можно почитать [тут](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html). Собственно 1 запросом можно и запихнуть весь файл в таблицу мускула.

Comment: LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/user/first.csv' INTO TABLE `firsttable` не работает